# Data approximation with unequal intervals

Tags: approximation

For some sampled function of real variable, defined on [a, b], how can [a, b] be split into subintervals of unequal width, so that for each interval one can say, "On this interval, function is approximately equal to ..."?

Formally speaking, function is to be approximated with several rectangles in some optimal way (e.g., with number of bins defined with Bayesian Information Criterion and with ranges and their values defined using minimum sum of squares) like this:

[image: Approximation with unequal width rectangles]

Do some methods or algorithms exist to accomplish this task?
Is "formally spoken" paragraph legitimate?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for piecewise linear approximations. Try searching for adaptive models.

Comment: You will need to make assumptions about the function if you want to make any progress, assumptions that lead to bounds on how much it can vary between samples.  You also need to be specific about what you mean by "optimal way": in particular, will there be any penalty for using more intervals in the approximation?

Comment: @tchakravarty Perhaps, _piecewise constant function_. Thanks, I'll search for that.

Comment: @whuber I thought Bayesian Information Criterion is how number of pieces is defined.

Comment: I guess I could make sense of that if we were to understand your question as asking for a piecewise linear approximation to the *data* rather than to the unknown function.

Comment: @whuber I don't even know honestly how I can reformulate question so that it makes sense. I have some sampled function (or signal) and want to split interval it's defined into subintervals so that within each of them I can more or less informatively tell that function has some constant value. I think I got idea what to search for, I see that there are papers about some algorithms, so there is something to learn.

Comment: Piecewise linear subsumes piecewise constant. Look for adaptive regression.